# Ошибка Extra characters on line в TASM

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Язык - ассемблер. Компиляция - tasm + tlink

Необходимо умножить число на 3. Предположительно, что число может оказаться и отрицательным, из-за чего пытаюсь использовать `imul`

Строка кода вызывающая ошибку:

```
imul al,3d
```

Ошибка при выполнении tasm:

```
Extra characters on line
```

Читал в справке, что `imul`, с 2 операндами, выполняет операцию умножения со знаком, затем записывает результат в 1 операнд. Что мне и нужно получить. Однако, какой конкретно лишний символ я использовал, я понять не могу.

Comment: Судя по справке http://asmworld.ru/spravochnik-komand/imul/ двухоперандный imul бывает только с первым операндом r16 и более, с однобайтным r8 не бывает. И что такое 3d не совсем ясно. обычно все таки систему счисления принято указывать (3dh)

Comment: @Mike и как в моем случаи поступить? Принято среди кого? Нам так объяснили, мы так и делаем. Вообще не люблю когда нет четкости в таких вещах, лучше бы был 1 допустимый вариант. P.S. 3d - 3 decimal

Comment: использовать ax вместо al. тем более что результат умножения на 3d в al скорее всего не влезет

Comment: c использованием `ax` ошибка все та же

Comment: А под какой процессор вы собираете программу ? двух операндный imul появился только в 386 процессоре, у вас у начале программы указаны директивы, что надо использовать не менее чем 386 ? И кстати, можно просто использовать однооперандный синтаксис, первый параметр у вас все равно же ax

Comment: Если использовать однооперандный синтаксис, а именно `imul 3d`, то получаю 2 ошибки на данную строку `illegal immediate` и `Argument needs type override`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70357/discussion-between-opossum-and-mike).

Comment: Тогда еще раз откройте справку, ссылку на которую я дал в первом комменте и внимательно прочитайте то что касается одно операндного синтаксиса. вы там видите `imul imm8` ? вот и я не вижу, нельзя использовать непосредственное значение, только регистр или память (r/m8). В двух оперндном можно, но процессор должен быть подходящим